# Keeping the variables private and accessing them through a common function in JS

Tags: javascript, json

I want to make an Object that will contain all the **constant properties** and those properties can not be changed through outside world,

for example :

```
var Constants = (function(){
    this.server_port = 8888;
    this.server_name = '127.0.0.1';

    return ({
            getConstantValue : function(constantName){
                /*
                  Now this will return the property as per the name of the 
                  constant passed
                */
            }
    });
}());
```

So, now if someone say

```
Constants.getConstantValue('server_port');//will return 8888;
Constants.getConstantValue('server_name');//will return 127.0.0.1;
```

How that can be achieved, remember I don't want to expose the properties to outer world, please shed some light.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Closures!](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures) With a little refactoring:

```
var constants = (function() {
    var constList = {
        server_port : 8888,
        server_name : '127.0.0.1'
    };
    return ({
        getConstantValue : function(constantName) {
            return constList[constantName];
        }
    });
}());
```

Comment: Very clean, very concise. Even for invalid ````constantName````, it would return undefined

Answer (score 3):

A more natural way would be to use real properties, for example:

```
function Const(obj) {
    var o = {};
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(k) {
        o.__defineGetter__(k, function() { return obj[k] })
    });
    return o;
}
```

or

```
function Const(obj) {
    var o = {};
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(k) {
        o[k] = { writable: false, value: obj[k] }
    });
    return Object.create({}, o);
}
```

and then

```
config = new Const({
    'server_port': 8888,
    'server_name': '127.0.0.1'
})


console.log(config.server_name) // 127.0.0.1
config.server_name = 'blah'
console.log(config.server_name) // still 127.0.0.1
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4thhN/)):

```
var Constants = (function(){
    var server_port = 8888;
    var server_name = '127.0.0.1';

    return ({
            getConstantValue : function(constantName){
                if(constantName == "server_port")
                {
                    return server_port;
                }
            }
    });
}());
```

Comment: be careful: as more constants are added, the logic portion must be updated to reflect the new properties.